# Bubble sort a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, bubble-sort

I've gone through a bunch of threads trying to understand what is going on exactly with linked lists and bubblesort, and I think I get the bulk of it.

Right now my program is simply crashing when I get to the sort function and I am not sure why. Hopefully another set of eyes will see what I do not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

DoublyList.h:

```
#include "listNode.h"

#ifndef DOUBLYLIST_H
#define DOUBLYLIST_H

template <typename T>
class DoublyList
{
    public:
        DoublyList();
        ~DoublyList();
        void addFront(T d);
        void addBack(T d);
        T removeFront();
        T removeBack();
        T peak();
        bool isEmpty();
        int getSize();
        void printList();
        void sortList();

    private:
        ListNode<T> *front;
        ListNode<T> *back;
        int numOfElements;
};

template <typename T>
DoublyList<T>::DoublyList(){
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
    numOfElements = 0;
}
template <typename T>
DoublyList<T>::~DoublyList(){
    if(numOfElements!=0){

        ListNode<T> *current;
        current = front;
        while (current != back)
        {
            ListNode<T> *temp = current;
            current = current->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
            temp->prev = NULL;
            delete temp;
            numOfElements--;
        }
        //at this point current = back, now delete it
        current->next = NULL;
        current->prev = NULL;
        delete current;
        numOfElements--;
    }
    //this is a safeguard if you create a LL and then delete it without doing anything to it
    else{
        cout<<"deleted empty LL"<<endl;
        delete front;
        delete back;
    }
}
template <typename T>
void DoublyList<T>::addFront(T d)
{
    ListNode<T> *node = new ListNode<T>();
    node->data = d;
    if (isEmpty()){
        back = node;
    }
    else{
        front->prev = node;
    }
    node->next = front;
    front = node;
    ++numOfElements;
}
template <typename T>
T DoublyList<T>::removeFront()
{
    if (isEmpty()){
        return T();
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode<T>* temp = front;
        if (front->next == 0){
            back = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            front->next->prev = 0;
        }
        front = front->next;
        temp->next = 0;
        T theData = temp->data;
        delete temp;
        --numOfElements;
        return theData;
    }
}
template <typename T>
void DoublyList<T>::addBack(T d)
{
    ListNode<T> *node = new ListNode<T>();
    node->data = d;
    if (isEmpty()){
        front = node;
    }
    else{
        back->next = node;
    }
    node->prev = back;
    back = node;
    ++numOfElements;
}
template <typename T>
T DoublyList<T>::removeBack()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return T();
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode<T>* temp;
        temp = back;
        if (back->prev == 0){
            front = 0;
        }
        else{
            back->prev->next = 0;
        }
        back = back->prev;
        temp->prev = 0;    
        T theData = temp->data;
        delete temp;
        --numOfElements;
        return theData;
    }
}
template <typename T>
T DoublyList<T>::peak()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return T();
    }
    return front->data;
}
template <typename T>
int DoublyList<T>::getSize(){
    return numOfElements;
}
template <typename T>
bool DoublyList<T>::isEmpty(){
    if(numOfElements == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
template <typename T>
void DoublyList<T>::printList(){
    if(numOfElements!=0){
        ListNode<T> *current = front;
        while(current!=back)
        {
            cout<<current->data<<endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
        cout<<back->data<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"list is empty"<<endl;
    }
}


template <typename T>
void DoublyList<T>::sortList(){
    int size = getSize();
    ListNode<T> *current;
    ListNode<T> *dummy;
    ListNode<T> *next;

    if(current == NULL) return;
    if(current -> next == NULL) return;

    int swapped = 1;
    while(swapped){
        swapped = 0; //last pass unless there is a swap
        while(current -> next != NULL){
            if(current-> data < current -> next -> data){
                swapped = 1; //swap, will need to re-enter while loop
                //actual number swap
                dummy -> data = current -> data;
                current -> data = current -> next -> data;
                current -> next -> data = dummy -> data;
            }
            current = current -> next;
        }
    }

}

#endif
```

listNode.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef LISTNODE_H
#define LISTNODE_H

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class ListNode
{
    public:
        T data;//the data that we will store
        ListNode();
        ListNode(int d);
        ~ListNode();
        ListNode *next;//int and ptr and the member variables
        ListNode *prev;
};
template <typename T>
ListNode<T>::ListNode(int d){
    data = d;
    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
}
template <typename T>
ListNode<T>::ListNode(){}
template <typename T>
ListNode<T>::~ListNode(){
    delete next;
    delete prev;
    cout<<"deleted Node"<<endl;
}
#endif
```

testList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "doublyList.h"
#include "genericQueue.h"




int main(){
    DoublyList<int> testQueue;
    testQueue.addBack(3);
    testQueue.addBack(5);
    testQueue.addBack(2);
    testQueue.addBack(10);
    testQueue.addBack(1);

    cout << "Before Sort: " << endl;
    testQueue.printList();

    cout << "After Sort: " << endl;
    testQueue.sortList();
    testQueue.printList();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: If I may ask: where did you get your code from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erors I could find so far are:

1. Your default `ListNode()` constructor doesn't null the `next` and `prev` pointers.
2. In `void DoublyList<T>::sortList()` you don't initialize `dummy`, so it just points into nowhere. Actually there is no reason to use a node list at all, you can just directly use a variable of type `T`.
3. You don't initialize `current` in the same function and you actually should reset `current` to e.g. `front` at the beginning of each outer loop.
4. You don't use `next` at all (and don't need to), so just remove it.

To sum it up, this is what `void DoublyList<T>::sortList()` could look like:

```
template <typename T>
void DoublyList<T>::sortList(){
    int size = getSize();
    ListNode<T> *current=front;
    T dummy;

    if (current == NULL) return;
    if (current->next == NULL) return;

    int swapped = 1;
    while (swapped){
        current = front;
        swapped = 0; //last pass unless there is a swap
        while (current->next != NULL){
            if (current->data < current->next->data){
                swapped = 1; //swap, will need to re-enter while loop
                //actual number swap
                dummy = current->data;
                current->data = current->next->data;
                current->next->data = dummy;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my suggestion for the ListNode constructor.

```
template <typename T>
ListNode<T>::ListNode() :
    next(nullptr), 
    prev(nullptr), 
    data{}
{}
```

Besides that, I also agree with DaveB that swapping pointers is the approach you should actually use.

Answer (score 0):

To start with you need to initialize current in your sort function,

```
current = first; 


template <typename T>
void DoublyList<T>::sortList(){

ListNode<T> *current;
ListNode<T> *next;

T tmp;
current = front;
if(current == NULL) return;
if(current -> next == NULL) return;

int swapped = 1;
while(swapped){
    swapped = 0; //last pass unless there is a swap
    while(current->next != nullptr){
        if(current->data < current->next->data){
            swapped = 1; //swap, will need to re-enter while loop
            //actual number swap
            tmp = current->data;
            current->data = current->next->data;
            current->next->data = tmp;
        }
        current = current -> next;  
    }
    if (swapped)          // go back to start of list for next pass
       current = front;
}
```

}

Comment: I set `ListNode<T> *current = peak();` and moved my code to visual studio to debug, but I am now getting this error: `Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'ListNode<T> *' c:\users\tylor\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\doublylist.h 181 1 ConsoleApplication1`

Comment: peak() returns the contents of the data member.  In your sort function current is a pointer to a ListNode object. You need to start with current pointing to the first ListNode object in your list so current = first;

Comment: you are also quoting too soon, as you wrote it you are only doing one pass, you have to keep making passes until no elements are out of order

Comment: I edited my answer with an updated sortList function that works. You should really swap the two elements by changing the ListNode elements position in the list, not by assigning the data member. It's much more efficient to swap a few pointers than to move a large object.